# Efficient way to generate combinations ordered by increasing sum of indexes

Tags: c#, performance, combinations

For a heuristic algorithm I need to evaluate, one after the other, the combinations of a certain set until I reach a stop criterion.

Since they are a lot, at the moment I'm generating them using the following memory efficient iterator block (inspired by python's [`itertools.combinations`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)):

```
public static IEnumerable<T[]> GetCombinations<T>(this IList<T> pool, int r)
{
    int n = pool.Count;
    if (r > n)
        throw new ArgumentException("r cannot be greater than pool size");
    int[] indices = Enumerable.Range(0, r).ToArray();
    yield return indices.Select(idx => pool[idx]).ToArray();
    while (true)
    {
        int i;
        for (i = r - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            if (indices[i] != i + n - r)
                break;
        if (i < 0)
            break;
        indices[i] += 1;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < r; j++)
            indices[j] = indices[j - 1] + 1;
        yield return indices.Select(idx => pool[idx]).ToArray();
    }
}
```

The problem is, to greatly improve the efficiency of my heuristic, I'd need to generate these combinations sorted by the sum of they indexes (in other words I need to generate first, the combinations containing the first elements of the set).

**e.g.**
Consider the set `S = {0,1,2,3,4,5}`
(I choose this set for simplicity since elements and their indexes coincide).
All possible combinations of `r=4` numbers generated from the given algorithm are:

```
(0, 1, 2, 3)  SUM:  6
(0, 1, 2, 4)  SUM:  7
(0, 1, 2, 5)  SUM:  8
(0, 1, 3, 4)  SUM:  8
(0, 1, 3, 5)  SUM:  9
(0, 1, 4, 5)  SUM: 10
(0, 2, 3, 4)  SUM:  9
(0, 2, 3, 5)  SUM: 10
(0, 2, 4, 5)  SUM: 11
(0, 3, 4, 5)  SUM: 12
(1, 2, 3, 4)  SUM: 10
(1, 2, 3, 5)  SUM: 11
(1, 2, 4, 5)  SUM: 12
(1, 3, 4, 5)  SUM: 13
(2, 3, 4, 5)  SUM: 14
```

where, as you can see, the combinations are not strictly sorted by ascending sum.

The desired outcome is instead the following :
(the order of the combinations having the same sum is not important)

```
(0, 1, 2, 3)  SUM:  6
(0, 1, 2, 4)  SUM:  7
(0, 1, 2, 5)  SUM:  8
(0, 1, 3, 4)  SUM:  8
(0, 1, 3, 5)  SUM:  9
(0, 2, 3, 4)  SUM:  9
(0, 1, 4, 5)  SUM: 10
(0, 2, 3, 5)  SUM: 10
(1, 2, 3, 4)  SUM: 10
(0, 2, 4, 5)  SUM: 11
(1, 2, 3, 5)  SUM: 11
(0, 3, 4, 5)  SUM: 12
(1, 2, 4, 5)  SUM: 12
(1, 3, 4, 5)  SUM: 13
(2, 3, 4, 5)  SUM: 14
```

A trivial solution would be to generate all the combinations then sort them according to their sum; but this is not really efficient/feasible since the number of combinations becomes huge as `n` grows.

I also had a quick look to combinatorial Gray Codes but I couldn't find anyone suitable for this problem.

Do you have an idea on how to implement something like this ?

**EDIT :**

This problem has an alternate (unfortunately not easier) formulation.
Given a set `S` and a number `r`, all the possible sums are trivial to find, since they are simply all the numbers from the sum of the first `r` elements of `S` to the sum of the last `r` elements of `S`.

That being said, if, for each sum `T` we can efficiently¹ find all the combinations having sum `T` we solve the original problem since we simply generate them in ascending order.

¹ efficiently means that I don't want to generate all the combinations and discard the ones having a different sum.

**EDIT 2:**

After @EricLippert suggestion I created the following code:

```
public static IEnumerable<T[]> 
GetCombinationsSortedByIndexSum<T>(this IList<T> pool, int r)
{
    int n = pool.Count;
    if (r > n)
        throw new ArgumentException("r cannot be greater than pool size");
    int minSum = ((r - 1) * r) / 2;
    int maxSum = (n * (n + 1)) / 2 - ((n - r - 1) * (n - r)) / 2;

    for (int sum = minSum; sum <= maxSum; sum++)
    {
        foreach (var indexes in AllMonotIncrSubseqOfLenMWhichSumToN(0, n - 1, r, sum))
            yield return indexes.Select(x => pool[x]).ToArray();
    }
}

static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> 
AllMonotIncrSubseqOfLenMWhichSumToN(int seqFirstElement, int seqLastElement, int m, int n)
{
    for (int i = seqFirstElement; i <= seqLastElement - m + 1; i++)
    {
        if (m == 1)
        {
            if (i == n)
                yield return new int[] { i };
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var el in AllMonotIncrSubseqOfLenMWhichSumToN(i + 1, seqLastElement, m - 1, n - i))
                yield return new int[] { i }.Concat(el);
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine (hopefully is what Eric meant :P) but I'm still concerned about the complexity of the recursive method. In fact it seems that we're regenerating all the combinations for each sum discarding the ones not summing up to the desired value.

To reduce the complexity of the inner function I found a way to limit the iterations by using effective upper and lower bounds (and now it's really hard to say what is the complexity of this).

Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16758273/316644) to see the final code.

Comment: does not answer your question as stated but would you be open to using an `OrderedDictionary` or perhaps even just a simple `Dictionary<int, List<int[]>>` which you could use to store groups of sets that have the same sum ?

Comment: @wal: well, as I said I can't store the combinations since they're too many. Anyway, if you have a fast way to generate all the combinations having a certain sum that would be an alternate solution to my problem :)

Comment: if you dont have an issue calculating them but dont want to *store* them all can you just discard/ignore that dont have the SUM youre looking for?

Comment: @wal But he's not looking to discard any; he's looking to get all of them, but in ascending order.

Comment: `fast way to generate all the combinations having a certain sum` <-- what do you do with the others that dont have a 'certain sum' ?

Comment: @wal: added an edit to my question ;)

Comment: @wal If he has a way to *quickly* generate all combinations for one sum then he can do that for each sum, in ascending order.  Your method isn't a *fast* way of generating the combinations for one sum as it's generating all of the combinations.  It would mean he'd need to generate each combination N times, where N is the size of the collection.  Combinations are already N!, so your algorithm would bump it up to N*(N!).  That's...bad.

Comment: yes @Servy understood but was just establishing what the specs were (which changed mid question ;))

Comment: @wal No, they didn't change in any way.  They are *exactly* the same as they were before, the OP merely proposed one possible approach for solving the problem, which relied on a task that he also doesn't know how to do; he was stating that if you can solve either of these two problems that solution can be used to solve his real problem.

Comment: @Servy fair enough and agreed

Comment: Can you describe your real scenario problem, including the maximum number of elements in the set (N), and the worst case the worst case number they can be grouped by (N/2).  Would a technique that allows you to specify an index into the set (without having to generate all the combinations before it) be useful?

Comment: @BobBryan: N should not pass 30-35 and R can be at most 10... sorry, but I didn't get what you mean by "specify an index into the set"...

Comment: This problem can be efficiently solved but I don't have time today to type up a lengthy sketch. A brief sketch is: can you write a recursive method called `AllMonotonicallyIncreasingSubsequencesOfLengthMWhichSumToN(Sequence<int>, int m, int n)` ? If you can write that recursive method then you can solve your problem.

Comment: The recursive base cases are obvious when the length m is zero or the sum is negative. The recursive case is: for each element in the sequence, remove it and produce the sequence which is the tail of the sequence -- the elements after that element. Now, recurse: what are all the subsequences of length m-1 from the tail that add to n minus the removed element?  Once you have that set of sequences, you've solved your problem.

Comment: @EricLippert: thanks I added an edit to my question (hopefully is more or less what you meant). Still doubtful about the complexity of the recursion but I haven't thought to it deeply yet...

Comment: You'll find that the complexity is reasonable. Note that your method is badly named now since "n" and "sum" have different meanings.

Comment: @EricLippert: yes, of corse thank you. If you want to form an answer I'll gladly accept it :)

Comment: @EricLippert: I studied the recursive function a little more and it seems to me that we're basically regenerating all the combinations discarding the ones which don't sum to N... maybe I didn't implement exactly what you meant?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution I had in mind was:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
class Program
{
  // Preconditions:
  // * items is a sequence of non-negative monotone increasing integers
  // * n is the number of items to be in the subsequence
  // * sum is the desired sum of that subsequence.
  // Result:
  // A sequence of subsequences of the original sequence where each 
  // subsequence has n items and the given sum.
  static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> M(IEnumerable<int> items, int sum, int n)
  {
    // Let's start by taking some easy outs. If the sum is negative
    // then there is no solution. If the number of items in the
    // subsequence is negative then there is no solution.

    if (sum < 0 || n < 0)
      yield break;

    // If the number of items in the subsequence is zero then
    // the only possible solution is if the sum is zero.

    if (n == 0)
    {
      if (sum == 0)
        yield return Enumerable.Empty<int>();
      yield break;
    }

    // If the number of items is less than the required number of 
    // items, there is no solution.

    if (items.Count() < n)
      yield break;

    // We have at least n items in the sequence, and
    // and n is greater than zero, so First() is valid:

    int first = items.First();

    // We need n items from a monotone increasing subsequence
    // that have a particular sum. We might already be too 
    // large to meet that requirement:

    if (n * first > sum)
      yield break;

    // There might be some solutions that involve the first element.
    // Find them all.

    foreach(var subsequence in M(items.Skip(1), sum - first, n - 1))
      yield return new[]{first}.Concat(subsequence);      

    // And there might be some solutions that do not involve the first element.
    // Find them all.

    foreach(var subsequence in M(items.Skip(1), sum, n))
      yield return subsequence;
  }
  static void Main()
  {
    int[] x = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    for (int i = 0; i <= 15; ++i)
      foreach(var seq in M(x, i, 4))
        Console.WriteLine("({0}) SUM {1}", string.Join(",", seq), i);
  }
}
```

The output is your desired output.

I've made no attempt to optimize this. It would be interesting to profile it and see where most of the time is spent.

UPDATE: Just for fun I wrote a version that uses an immutable stack instead of an arbitrary enumerable. Enjoy!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

abstract class ImmutableList<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
  public static readonly ImmutableList<T> Empty = new EmptyList();
  private ImmutableList() {}  
  public abstract bool IsEmpty { get; }
  public abstract T Head { get; }
  public abstract ImmutableList<T> Tail { get; }
  public ImmutableList<T> Push(T newHead)
  {
    return new List(newHead, this);
  }  

  private sealed class EmptyList : ImmutableList<T>
  {
    public override bool IsEmpty { get { return true; } }
    public override T Head { get { throw new InvalidOperationException(); } }
    public override ImmutableList<T> Tail { get { throw new InvalidOperationException(); } }
  }
  private sealed class List : ImmutableList<T>
  {
    private readonly T head;
    private readonly ImmutableList<T> tail;
    public override bool IsEmpty { get { return false; } }
    public override T Head { get { return head; } }
    public override ImmutableList<T> Tail { get { return tail; } }
    public List(T head, ImmutableList<T> tail)
    {
      this.head = head;
      this.tail = tail;
    }
  }
  System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
  {
    return this.GetEnumerator();
  }
  public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
  {
    for (ImmutableList<T> current = this; !current.IsEmpty; current = current.Tail)
      yield return current.Head;
  }
}  

class Program
{
  // Preconditions:
  // * items is a sequence of non-negative monotone increasing integers
  // * n is the number of items to be in the subsequence
  // * sum is the desired sum of that subsequence.
  // Result:
  // A sequence of subsequences of the original sequence where each 
  // subsequence has n items and the given sum.
  static IEnumerable<ImmutableList<int>> M(ImmutableList<int> items, int sum, int n)
  {
    // Let's start by taking some easy outs. If the sum is negative
    // then there is no solution. If the number of items in the
    // subsequence is negative then there is no solution.

    if (sum < 0 || n < 0)
      yield break;

    // If the number of items in the subsequence is zero then
    // the only possible solution is if the sum is zero.
    if (n == 0)
    {
      if (sum == 0)
        yield return ImmutableList<int>.Empty;
      yield break;
    }

    // If the number of items is less than the required number of 
    // items, there is no solution.

    if (items.Count() < n)
      yield break;

    // We have at least n items in the sequence, and
    // and n is greater than zero.
    int first = items.Head;

    // We need n items from a monotone increasing subsequence
    // that have a particular sum. We might already be too 
    // large to meet that requirement:

    if (n * first > sum)
      yield break;

    // There might be some solutions that involve the first element.
    // Find them all.

    foreach(var subsequence in M(items.Tail, sum - first, n - 1))
      yield return subsequence.Push(first);      

    // And there might be some solutions that do not involve the first element.
    // Find them all.
    foreach(var subsequence in M(items.Tail, sum, n))
      yield return subsequence;
  }
  static void Main()
  {
    ImmutableList<int> x = ImmutableList<int>.Empty.Push(5).
                           Push(4).Push(3).Push(2).Push(1).Push(0);
    for (int i = 0; i <= 15; ++i)
      foreach(var seq in M(x, i, 4))
        Console.WriteLine("({0}) SUM {1}", string.Join(",", seq), i);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason why are you writing your own immutable stack instead of using the one from Microsoft.Bcl.Immutable?

Comment: @svick: It's more pedagogic this way.

Comment: Thanks that's very useful (and the immutable stack part is really interesting) :)  It is pretty similar to my approach actually, I just exploited the fact that, in my particular case, sequences are **always** consecutive increasing integers. Hence, I can generate effective lowerbounds (see my last edit) which cut down the number of recursions **a lot** and is much faster. Anyway, I'll accept this since it's the origin of my final code :)

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness and clarity I'll post my final code:

```
// Given a pool of elements returns all the 
// combinations of the groups of lenght r in pool, 
// such that the combinations are ordered (ascending) by the sum of 
// the indexes of the elements.
// e.g. pool = {A,B,C,D,E} r = 3
// returns
// (A, B, C)   indexes: (0, 1, 2)   sum: 3
// (A, B, D)   indexes: (0, 1, 3)   sum: 4
// (A, B, E)   indexes: (0, 1, 4)   sum: 5
// (A, C, D)   indexes: (0, 2, 3)   sum: 5
// (A, C, E)   indexes: (0, 2, 4)   sum: 6
// (B, C, D)   indexes: (1, 2, 3)   sum: 6
// (A, D, E)   indexes: (0, 3, 4)   sum: 7
// (B, C, E)   indexes: (1, 2, 4)   sum: 7
// (B, D, E)   indexes: (1, 3, 4)   sum: 8
// (C, D, E)   indexes: (2, 3, 4)   sum: 9
public static IEnumerable<T[]>
GetCombinationsSortedByIndexSum<T>(this IList<T> pool, int r)
{
    int n = pool.Count;
    if (r > n)
        throw new ArgumentException("r cannot be greater than pool size");
    int minSum = F(r - 1);
    int maxSum = F(n) - F(n - r - 1);

    for (int sum = minSum; sum <= maxSum; sum++)
    {
        foreach (var indexes in AllSubSequencesWithGivenSum(0, n - 1, r, sum))
            yield return indexes.Select(x => pool[x]).ToArray();
    }
}


// Given a start element and a last element of a sequence of consecutive integers
// returns all the monotonically increasing subsequences of length "m" having sum "sum"
// e.g. seqFirstElement = 1, seqLastElement = 5, m = 3, sum = 8
//      returns {1,2,5} and {1,3,4}
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>
AllSubSequencesWithGivenSum(int seqFirstElement, int seqLastElement, int m, int sum)
{
    int lb = sum - F(seqLastElement) + F(seqLastElement - m + 1);
    int ub = sum - F(seqFirstElement + m - 1) + F(seqFirstElement);

    lb = Math.Max(seqFirstElement, lb);
    ub = Math.Min(seqLastElement - m + 1, ub);

    for (int i = lb; i <= ub; i++)
    {
        if (m == 1)
        {
            if (i == sum) // this check shouldn't be necessary anymore since LB/UB should automatically exclude wrong solutions
                yield return new int[] { i };
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var el in AllSubSequencesWithGivenSum(i + 1, seqLastElement, m - 1, sum - i))
                yield return new int[] { i }.Concat(el);
        }
    }
}

// Formula to compute the sum of the numbers from 0 to n
// e.g. F(4) = 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10
static int F(int n)
{
    return (n * (n + 1)) / 2;
}
```